# Removing archaic print() calls in writing PHP template

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a PHP template that I am using to create a HTML page from a SQL database. I know that the way I am going about it is a little archaic, but don't know how to begin fixing it. Here is a sample of the code, where I am creating a button from the SQL database. All of the $ variables are created prior to this in the PHP code. I am calling a function watchshow() when the button is pressed.  Is there another way I should be writing this without print()? I hope this question is specific enough!

```
 print("<td><a  id=$currentshow_id class='$classname showButton' onclick=\"watchshow('$currentshow_id' , '$checked', '$currentshow_genre' );\">$currentshow_title</a></td>"); 
 print("<td class = 'genre'>{$offered_show["showgenre"]}</td>");
```

Comment: there is a lot different you can do.  If you need to include your presentation structure within your logic code, you "could" place your desired output in a variable, appending the html.  Then echo the output when done/ready.

Comment: Maybe use a templating language...? http://twig.sensiolabs.org, http://phptal.org

Comment: Can you explain why it is preferable to do this instead of the print() call I have above?

Comment: Because a proper templating language forcibly divorces business logic from template code, forcing you into separated, more maintainable code. This also makes both parts of your code more readable, hence more maintainable, more extensible. It takes care of escaping things properly, or at least simplifies it a lot. It makes your templates more reusable than if they're baked into a bunch of PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace print() with echo, and use a multi-line string to make it easier to read:

```
echo "<td><a id=$currentshow_id class='$classname showButton' 
            onclick=\"watchshow('$currentshow_id', '$checked', '$currentshow_genre')\"
            >$currentshow_title</a></td>
      <td class='genre'>{$offered_show['showgenre']}</td>
";
```

You can simplify the code in each `<a>`:

```
echo "<td><a id=$currentshow_id
            class='$classname showButton' 
            data-checked='$checked'
            data-genre='$currentshow_genre'
            onclick='watchshow(this)'
            >$currentshow_title</a></td>
      <td class='genre'>{$offered_show['showgenre']}</td>
";

function watchshow(el) {
    var id = el.id;
    var checked = el.getAttribute('checked');
    var genre = el.getAttribute('genre');
    //...
}
```